# Plot Issues - Start always in (0,0)

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am working with a huge data set where all columns look something like this:
0
10
12
30
10
0
20
30
0
40
50
10
0

The idea is to make a simple plot in R where every time it reads a 0 the plot will begin in (0,0).
Do you have any idea of how I can do this?

Thanks in advance,
J

UPDATE:
I am a new user so I can't post any images!
Here's an example of the column I want to plot:

0
10
20
12
5
6
9
0
20
24
40
14
0
20
59
50
12
0
20
23
49
45
23
12
(...)

Image a line plot.
Instead of plotting a long line with all the values I want to plot several shorter lines with the first line plotting (0,10,20,12,5,6,9), the second line plotting (0,20,24,40,14) etc...

Comment: Perhaps you could show us a little preview to your data (try `your.data[1:5, 1:5]`). A sketch of what the output should look like would also be helpful. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: Dear @RomanLuštrik I updated my question in order to make it more clear.
I wanted to add a few images to show what I want but, as a new user, I can't post any images.

Answer (score 0):

I would add an additional column specifying which subdataset your are:

```
Value  Group
0      1
1      1
5      1
0      2
Etc.
```

You can then plot the subgroups using e.g. `ggplot2`:

```
ggplot(yourdata, aes(x = xcoor, y = Value, color = Group)) + 
    geom_line()
```

Which will draw the lines with different colors. Or using `plot` using something like:

```
split_dat = with(yourdata, split(Value, Group))
plot(split_dat[[1]])
for(i in 2:length(split_dat)) {
   lines(split_dat[[i]])
 }
```

Comment: Dear @Paul Hiemstra,

Thank you very much for your reply!
If I use your approach I would still need to manually add a column to every file, right?
Or is there a way to do it automatically?
thanks!

Comment: You can use the order in the data to generate the second colunn, i.e. the number needs to become larger for every 0.

Comment: Using a combination of `which` and `rep` should get you started.

Comment: You could get the 2nd column using something like `cumsum(x==0)`.